# Most performant overwriting file multiple times

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to work out which is faster, but sadly I have Sophos installed (unable to remove due to work restrictions) and I think (know) it's throwing off my results, so I thought best to ask the experts.

I am writing to a file in a synchronous loop. (I am not writing a node server, it's a single use task, sync will be fine).

Now, I am either keep making a new file descriptor each time with writeFileSync, but using the same file descriptor with writeSync ftruncateSync I believe would be faster.

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Method 1
const fd = fs.openSync('./test.txt', 'w');
fs.writeSync(fd, 'hello1', 0, 'utf-8');
fs.ftruncateSync(fd, 0); // truncate because next content my be shorter
fs.writeSync(fd, 'hello2', 0, 'utf-8');
fs.ftruncateSync(fd, 0); // truncate because next content my be shorter
fs.writeSync(fd, 'bye3', 0, 'utf-8');
fs.closeSync(fd);

// Method 2
fs.writeFileSync('./test.txt', 'hello1', 'utf-8');
fs.writeFileSync('./test.txt', 'hello2', 'utf-8');
fs.writeFileSync('./test.txt', 'bye3', 'utf-8');
```

I know method 1 is more lines, but to me it should be faster to overwrite the content each time. But I am hoping someone will prove me wrong.

Or if anyone knows if I can do writeSync+truncate in 1 go, that would be even better.

Other synchronous suggestions of completing this task are welcome.

Comment: Questions: is the current setup not fast enough for your needs? If speed is so important, why node.js? What kind of data and how much? Where's it coming from? There's a lot of missing context here...

Comment: I am gonna be writing to this file roughly 20 trillion times. (13 factorial). Any speed increase will be significant by the end

Comment: 16 factorial, and it's the language the modules I'm using are. Everything is synchronous

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you're going to gain anything by going async (you *might* be able to make gains by using multiple threads or since it's JS multiple processes). If I were you I'd start thinking about ways to batch writes. At 16! writes drive I/O (even on an SSD) is going to limit you way more than anything you do or don't do in the programming language. I think you're going to need to tell us more about what you're *actually* trying to do here. What is this data that you need trillions and trillions of *individual* writes?

Comment: The writes are actually just progress recording. I don't want to get 10trillion in, get a power cut and have to start again. 
I have limited it to writing a lot less by putting a counter in. I wont mind losing say the last 10000 results. I have already broken down the task into 16 discrete sections, to run multiple processes. (Though, I can only run 5 of the 16 at once before my CPU just hits 100%). I am now only doing 130 million writes per section.